# Word meaning 'to reduce its influence' or 'to deal with' in regards to an argument.

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing

> Point three is actually really interesting, but to[reduce its influence] I'll point out that [counter arguement].

What I'm getting at here, is that I'm not claiming to completely refute the argument, I just want to dismiss it as 'no big deal'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[dismiss](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dismiss)** would be apt here

> Treat as unworthy of serious consideration (Oxford)

You can also **[brush aside](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/brush-aside)/[shrug aside](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/shrug-off)** the argument. (IMO, `aside` is less strong than `off`, which you can use.)

---

Arguments can be **[weak](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/weak#weak__10)**. I don't think `weaken` is idiomatic here, but you can paraphrase it:

*Point three is actually really interesting, but weak/thin/flimsy (or overstated), as shown by [counter arguement].*

---

In case only a single word that means 'to reduce' will do, you could use **[undermine](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/undermine)**, (maybe)

> Lessen the effectiveness, power, or ability of, especially gradually or insidiously:

I'm not sure it works here, though.

---

For a single word that means 'to deal with', you could

[pursue/examine/analyze](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pursue%20the%20argument%2C%20analyse%20the%20argument%2C%20examine%20the%20argument&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpursue%20the%20argument%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canalyse%20the%20argument%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexamine%20the%20argument%3B%2Cc0) the argument. The ngram shows that `pursue` is the most idiomatic one.

Comment: I dont think he wants to dismiss it, but simply to argue against but not completely contradict

Comment: @nickson104: Yes. I'm still waiting for a single word that describes exactly that to come to me or someone else, if it exists at all.

Comment: I agree, I would really like to see such a word. There are many words that can be applied, but none I can think of to that exact meaning. Either way, this was a good answer, especially once expanded

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use the (more diplomatic) expression:

[To put things into (the right) perspective](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_something_into_perspective):

> - (idiomatic) To compare with something similar to give a clearer, more accurate idea.

Wiktionary

- Point three is actually really interesting, but to *put things into the right perspective* I'll point out that [counter arguement].

Answer (score 0):

I’ll try to address the “to deal with [arguments/points]” portion of your question with “[address](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/address)” or one of its single-word synonyms suggested by Merriam-Webster (handle/field/treat [or, if two words are ok, “respond to”]):

> 2 a: … b :  to deal with :  treat (intrigued by the chance to address
>   important issues — I. L. Horowitz)

In fact, if ‘Point 3’ is truly “[actually really] interesting” (and you’re not just saying so out of politeness), I’d still go with “address” (with some slight paraphrasing):

Although ‘Point Three’ is actually really interesting, I will/can address/respond to it by [simply] pointing out that [the earth is not flat/the center of the universe/whatever].